# Python HttpConnection - write request headers to file

Tags: python, http

I'm trying to log some connection info in the event that an error occurs.  Using httplib's HTTPConnection I can print out the request headers by setting the debug level to 1:

```
    connection = httplib.HTTPConnection('www.example.com')
    connection.set_debuglevel(1)
```

However, this just seems to print directly to the shell without conditions.  I need to be able to get this info as a string or something to store in a variable such that I only print it out when an Exception is thrown.

The specific info that I want is the request headers that the library is generating.

Comment: Perhaps you should use a higher-level module instead? `urllib2` in the stdlib, or `requests` or similar libraries as add-ons.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) HTTP library.

To get response headers, you just need this little piece of code:

```
import requests

try:
    r = requests.get("http://www.example.com")
    # Raise an exception in case of "bad"
    # status code (non-200 response)
    r.raise_for_status()
    print r.headers
except Exception as e:
    print e.message
```

Output:

```
{'connection': 'close',
 'content-encoding': 'gzip',
 'content-length': '1162',
 'content-type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
 'date': 'Sun, 12 Aug 2012 12:49:44 GMT',
 'last-modified': 'Wed, 09 Feb 2011 17:13:15 GMT',
 'server': 'Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)',
 'vary': 'Accept-Encoding'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the trick is to redirect sys.stdout to a StringIO object, the contents of which can then either be written to file or what ever you like as you can get to the String.  Check out StringIO.StringIO.